crontab syntax highlighting
Let's look at crontab -e in Emacs vs Vim.
Emacs
If I run crontab -e in Emacs:
EDITOR=emacs crontab -e

it looks like this:

So we basically have two colors. One for comments and one for crontab text.
Vim
In vim, the syntax highlighting is much richer:

comments

time/date

command
EDITOR=vim crontab -e



neovim
Similar for neovim:
EDITOR=nvim crontab -e


Question
Is there a way to get the richer syntax highlighting that vim provides for crontab in Emacs?

Have you set any theme?
It seems like without any theme set, emacs doesn't show crontab-mode's (timewise) syntax highlighting.



Ah... Ok... Let me try that. Thank you!

Yup, modus-vivendi theme did the trick. Thanks! I tried all the built-in themes and none of those showed different colors for the time fields.

It's a bug in the package, see my answer for a workaround to make it work with the default theme.

@matteol Ah, thank you!

There is a crontab-mode package in melpa.
You need to enable the melpa package repository,customizing the variable package-archives or adding the following to your emacs init file
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

then you can install it with
M-x package-install RET crontab-mode

The faces for the time fields are derived from ones defined in outline.elthat is not loaded by default. It's a little bug in the package, as a workaround you can add
(require 'outline)

to the emacs init file.

Looks like I already have it installed. list-packages shows: crontab-mode       20210715.133  installed             Major mode for crontab(5)
